# Unable to build android project due to problem with ninja

Tags: android

i have an android project with maply dependency and it was working fine but i dont know what happened it just wont build. here is the error when i try to build or make project->

```
Failure: Build failed with an exception
Execution failed for task ':maply:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
```

i tried to do seperate execution using grade-> `gradle :maply:externalNativeBuildDebug`
then i got this error->

```
ninja: build stopped: .
  
  ninja: error: mkdir(CMakeFiles/whirlyglobemaply.dir/---some path----: No such file or directory
```

anybody know what could be the problem? help...

Answer (score 1):

I only got the error with CMake and Ninja but my problem was caused by reaching the windows path length limit. For CMake there are some option (https://visualgdb.com/documentation/cmake/CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX/) maybe they could be transferred to your situation.